# working with array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have started to learn knockout API. I written this small piece of code, which is quite simple, but it's not working. Please help me out

```html
<h4>People(<span data-bind="text: controls().length"> </span>)</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach:controls">
    <li>
        Id: <span data-bind="text: controls.id"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click:$root.addControls">Add</button>
```

```js
var Form = function(){
    this.controls = [{id:"T1",type:"TextInput"},
                                     {id:"T2",type:"TextInput"}];
    this.addControls = function(){
    this.controls.push({id:"",type:""})           
    };

}

var Controls = function(id,type){
   this.id = id;
   this.type = type;              

}


ko.applyBindings(new Form());
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fTptZ/12/)

Comment: I am not getting the expected result. You can check the code

Comment: Your code contains quite a few syntax error such as using `=` instead of `:` in object literals and at one point you forgot the `{}` around your object literal.

Comment: Open javascript console in developer tools of browser.

Comment: OMG!..Sorry for silly mistakes and now that's been taken care. Still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ingro/fTptZ/38/

I don't know why it didn't work online but it's fine on a test page I made locally.

Anyway some of your mistakes:

1. controls should be a observableArray:

   ```
   self.controls = ko.observableArray([{id:"T1",type:"TextInput"}, {id:"T2",type:"TextInput"}]);
   ```
2. when you use a "foreach" bind you don't need to put the array as prefix:

   ```
   Id:<span data-bind="text: id"></span>
   ```
3. you used a old version of Knockout, 2.1.0 is out!

Hope this can help!